Change vue files in node_modules doesn't take effect
I want to modify a .vue file that is located in the node_modules folder, but when I change something in its code, these changes have no effect.
I know this is a bad approach, but I need it for a test
<template>
    <div :class="cx('root')" data-scrollselectors=".p-datatable-wrapper" v-bind="ptmi('root')">
      test test test test test test test  <<<<--------- my test changes 
        <slot></slot>
 ...

And as you can see, nothing has changed, the text hasn't appeared. The same will happen with anything else in this file: script or styles.
component in browser
I'm using Nuxt 3 + Vite, and PrimeVue3 for component library.
Here is Nuxt configuration:
import { resolve } from 'pathe'

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
  },

  css: ['~/assets/scss/main.scss'],

  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
  },

  vite: {
  },

  site: {
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
    trailingSlash: true,
  },

  security: {
    headers: {
      crossOriginEmbedderPolicy: 'unsafe-none',
      contentSecurityPolicy: {
        'img-src': ['\'self\'', 'data:', '*', 'blob:'],
        'connect-src': ['\'self\'', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000', 'https:'],
      },
      xXSSProtection: false,
    },
    xssValidator: false,
  },

  typescript: {
    typeCheck: 'build',
  },

  modules: ['@pinia/nuxt', '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt', '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', 'nuxt-graphql-middleware', '@nuxtjs/seo', 'nuxt-splide', '@nuxtjs/i18n', 'nuxt-icon', 'nuxt-primevue', '@nuxt/image', '@formkit/auto-animate/nuxt', '@vueuse/nuxt', 'nuxt-lodash', 'nuxt-security', 'nuxt-monaco-editor', '@nuxt/fonts'],

  imports: {
    dirs: ['gql', 'graphql'],
  },

  piniaPersistedstate: {
    cookieOptions: {
      sameSite: 'strict',
    },
    storage: 'cookies',
  },

  graphqlMiddleware: {
    graphqlEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT || 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql/',
    debug: true,
    devtools: true,
    outputDocuments: true,
    downloadSchema: true,
    autoImportPatterns: ['**/*.gql', '**/*.graphql'],
    enableFileUploads: true,
  },

  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      admin_suffix: 'tuz', // Це колись переробити
      file_upload_url: process.env.FILE_ULOAD_URL || 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/file_browser/upload_to_temp/?format=json',
    },
  },

  experimental: {
    defaults: {
      nuxtLink: {
        trailingSlash: 'append',
      },
    },
  },

  i18n: {
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'uk',
        name: 'UK',
        iso: 'uk-UA',
        file: 'uk.ts',
      },
      {
        code: 'en',
        name: 'EN',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'en.ts', // add file name for each locale
      },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'uk',

    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'locales',

    detectBrowserLanguage: false,

    vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts',
  },

  primevue: {
    usePrimeVue: true,
    options: {
      unstyled: true,
      ripple: true,
    },
    importPT: { from: resolve(__dirname, './assets/presets/wind/') },
    components: {
      prefix: 'Prime',
    },
    
  },

  compatibilityDate: '2024-08-21',

  devtools: {
    enabled: true,
  },
})

I have also tried to change non-vue files, regular .js and everything works fine if I clear the nuxt and vite cache with npx nuxi cleanup command, but with .vue it didn't work out and no changes have any effect.
Is there really no way to change .vue files inside node_modules?

Depends where you edit it I guess + possible caching.

@kissu Directly in the primevue component, I also tried to do the same in Buefy and got the same result - .js files change, .vue does not. I don't know if it's cached. I didn't find any cache in primevue, and the .nuxt and .vite cache is cleared by the command nuxi cleanup. Maybe there is a cache somewhere else? I've just recently started using vue and nuxt, so I may not know a lot.

How do you run your project? Why do you need to hack that in node modules btw? Seems like a lot of abstractions/things for someone that just starts working with Vue.

@kissu Usually I run it with “npm run dev”, but in this case I tried it with --force to re-bundle deps as advised in the vite documentation to clear the cache, because I thought maybe that was the problem. But it did nothing for the .vue files.
And I want to change it because I need emit for matchmode-change filters in the DataTable component. And to make it work, I just need to add 3 lines of code and my problem is solved, because the developers are not in a hurry to respond or add this feature, so it would be a temporary solution for me.
